# Can't bind to 'shouldLabelFloat' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

Tags: angular, angular-material

Based on the [api documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/input/api#MatInput), `shouldLabelFloat` is a property of `MatInput`. But I'm still getting the error.

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [shouldLabelFloat]="true" placeholder="First Name">
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: What's your version of Angular and Angular Material?

Comment: It's @angular/material: 5.1.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a bit of digging, it looks like the documentation site is a bit broken and shows properties that are meant to be private. There's currently a pull request that was already merged with this fix to remove private getters. Here's the [code](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/c7201984d4570e2bf17fbf4afce0dc4400f863f5/src/lib/input/input.ts#L330-L334) for more info.

---

Anyways, the correct property to use is the `floatLabel` input of `MatFormField` as follows:

```html
<mat-form-field floatLabel="always">
  <input matInput [(ngModel)]="firstName" placeholder="First name">
</mat-form-field>
```

The `floatLabel` input accepts three properties: `auto`, `always` or `never`.

---

Here's some references:

- [Api documentation for `MatFormField`](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/api#MatFormField)
- [Overview docs on placeholders](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview#floating-label)
- [Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/float-type-so)

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Nice digging Edric!

Answer (score 0):

You should user inside **`mat-form-field`**

```
 <mat-form-field shouldLabelFloat="true">
  <input  matInput type="text" [(ngModel)]="firstName"  placeholder="First Name">
```

Comment: Could you please provide a working link? It didn't work for me.

Comment: can you provide a stackblitz , i will modify

Comment: `shouldLabelFloat` is a getter which is meant to be private but docs had a problem with generation (most likely)